# C++ Windows API slower than ifstream? Is there another way?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

I have a 5MB tab delimited file that I need to read in. I was using `ifstream` and have also tried using `CreateFile` with `ReadFile` or `CreateFileMapping`, but both the windows implementations take slightly longer than using `ifstream`.

Am I missing something important? From SO and Google I was under the impression that using the windows api would speed it up.

Sorry for the large amount of code, I wanted to provide the complete functions as I have no idea where the problem may lie.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

ifstreams:

```
void ifstream_read(string file_name)
{
    string line, word;
    ifstream inf;
    vector<string> current_record;
    inf.open(file_name.c_str()); //char* 
    while (! inf.eof() )
    {
        current_record.clear();
        getline(inf, line);
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word)
        {
            current_record.push_back(word);
        }

            //save current_record in my dataset
    }

}
```

Windows with `ReadFile`:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8192

void windows_read(wstring file)
{
    HANDLE file_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPCWSTR file_name =  (LPCWSTR)file.c_str();
    DWORD  bytes_read = 0;
    char read_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};
    bool complete = false;
    stringstream ss;

    file_handle = CreateFile(file_name,            
                            GENERIC_READ,           // open for reading
                            NULL,                   // do not share
                            NULL,                   // default security
                            OPEN_EXISTING,      // existing file only
                            FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,  // normal file
                            NULL);
    while(!complete)
    {
        ReadFile(file_handle, read_buffer, BUFFER_SIZE-1, &bytes_read, NULL);

        if(bytes_read < BUFFER_SIZE-1)
        {
            complete = true;
            read_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
        }
        ss << read_buffer;
    }
    CloseHandle(file_handle);

    vector<string> current_record;
    string line, word;
    while(getline(ss, line, '\n'))
    {
        current_record.clear();
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word)
        {
            current_record.push_back(word);
        }

        //save current_record in my dataset
    }
}
```

Windows file mapping:

```
void windows_map(wstring file)
{
    HANDLE file_handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    LPCWSTR file_name =  (LPCWSTR)file.c_str();
    stringstream ss;

    file_handle = CreateFile(file_name,            
                            GENERIC_READ,           // open for reading
                            NULL,                   // do not share
                            NULL,                   // default security
                            OPEN_EXISTING,      // existing file only
                            FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN,  // normal file
                            NULL);

    HANDLE file_map = CreateFileMapping(file_handle, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
    LPVOID file_view = MapViewOfFile(file_map, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, 0);

    ss << (char*)file_view;

    UnmapViewOfFile(file_view);
    CloseHandle(file_map);
    CloseHandle(file_handle);

    vector<string> current_record;
    string line, word;
    while(getline(ss, line, '\n'))
    {
        current_record.clear();
        istringstream iss(line);
        while (iss >> word)
        {
            current_record.push_back(word);
        }

        // save current_record to dataset
    }
}
```

Comment: `ifstream` is built on `ReadFile` fundamentally, any difference is going to be due to the amount of data read each time.

Comment: You do quite a lot more in the `ReadFile` example. Having e.g. three loops (in total) compared to two can make quite a lot of difference.

Comment: Worth noting that `while (!eof())` is such a common source of bugs.

Comment: I had thought that using windows file mapping would be faster as it reads the whole file into memory, rather than accessing it from the disk each line, does ifstream do that under the hood anyway then? I understand that speed isn't everything it's just I assumed there was a problem with my implementation as all the sources i've found state that using the api should be faster? Perhaps it is and the bottle neck is parsing the file :/

Comment: The implementation of `ifstream` by necessity relies on `CreateFile` and `ReadFile`. Those Win32 API functions are the way files are read.
The C++ standard library is well designed and modern mainstream compilers have excellent implementations. If you want to improve performance you need to have a solid idea of why performance of your existing code is weak, and why the alternative would be better. Just randomly trying different APIs isn't liable to yield results. So, why is your current code slow, and how could it be improved? What are your performance constraints?

Comment: What's more, if you want us to comment on performance, it is only reasonable that you present the data you are using to measure performance. Code is not enough. Present input data, and your measured results.

Comment: @lex - "` file mapping would be faster as it reads the whole file into memory`" - Just stop right there. While in some instances, it may do so, this is by no means fixed in stone. There's 64bit addresses used - I dont know anyone that has enough ram to need 64 bits to address it all. Furthermore, `MapViewOfFile`'s 5th argument says how many bytes to map into memory - you've specified 0. :confused:

Comment: @enhzflep [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) states that 4th and 5th argument of the function left as 0 makes it load the entire file.

Comment: @lex - oh dear. Indeed. It looks like someone (me) failed to read the documentation correctly. I should have read the remarks section. Interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

So, you are comparing speed of one vehicle with 2 passengers on it, and another one which is fully loaded with luggage in back of the vehicle. You cant call such thing as comparison. Run both vehicles with same loading, on same road, and same road and weather conditions.

Likewise, don't use byte-by-byte copying into C-string, then pushing it in vector. In my opinion, just read the contents into memory, and see how fast different approaches read. I would say, don't even use some large memory (huge `new`ed array, or a vector). Just use a single buffer (or `string` object), and keep overwriting it.

Do a release build to do performance testing, on exactly same file (on same drive).